# Reducing foreach loops for a tuple search in a list of tuples

Tags: c#

I have following code to check whether a tuple is present inside a list of tuples. This is working fine – but it is iterating using 3 foreach loops. Is there a way to reduce the foreach loops?

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XtVHPn)

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, String>> allLOINCDatesForPatient = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
allLOINCDatesForPatient.Add(Tuple.Create<DateTime, String>(new DateTime(2018, 7, 8), "4548-4A"));
allLOINCDatesForPatient.Add(Tuple.Create<DateTime, String>(new DateTime(2018, 7, 8), "4548-4B"));
allLOINCDatesForPatient.Add(Tuple.Create<DateTime, String>(new DateTime(2018, 7, 1), "4548-4G"));
allLOINCDatesForPatient.Add(Tuple.Create<DateTime, String>(new DateTime(2018, 7, 1), "4548-4H"));

AnalyteDTO analyteDTO = new AnalyteDTO();
analyteDTO.loinc = "4548-4A";
List<AnalyteDTO> analyteDTOList = new List<AnalyteDTO>();
analyteDTOList.Add(analyteDTO);
DateTime observationDate = new DateTime(2018, 7, 8);
OneDayAnalytes oneDayAnalytes = new OneDayAnalytes();
oneDayAnalytes.Analytes = analyteDTOList;
oneDayAnalytes.ObservationDate = observationDate;

List<OneDayAnalytes> observationsList = new List<OneDayAnalytes>();
observationsList.Add(oneDayAnalytes);


foreach (OneDayAnalytes o in observationsList)
{
    bool isNew = true;
    foreach (AnalyteDTO a in o.Analytes)
    {
        string databaseLOINC = a.loinc;
        DateTime databaseDate = o.ObservationDate.Date;

        foreach (Tuple<DateTime, String> lst in allLOINCDatesForPatient)
        {
            if (lst.Item1.Date == databaseDate && lst.Item2.Equals(databaseLOINC))
            {
                isNew = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Is New?  -->> "+ isNew.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Classes**

```
public class AnalyteDTO
{
    public string analytename { get; set; }
    public string loinc { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
    public float value { get; set; }
}

public class OneDayAnalytes
{
    public List<AnalyteDTO> Analytes { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObservationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could change `allLOINCDatesForPatient` to a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`. This can eliminate the innermost loop.

Comment: Why do you initialize a `List<OneDayAnalytes>` from a single `OneDayAnalytes`?  Are there typically multiple entries in the list?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes there are thousands of entries in that list (for each patient) in real scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how much more readable you'd think this is, but you could use a double `Any()`:

```
foreach (OneDayAnalytes o in observationsList)
{
    bool isNew = !o.Analytes
        .Any(a => allLOINCDatesForPatient
            .Any(lst => lst.Item1.Date == o.ObservationDate.Date && lst.Item2.Equals(a.loinc)));

    Console.WriteLine("Is New?  -->> " + isNew.ToString());
}
```

Notice that, unlike your implementation, this would break the loop upon the first match.
The code to match this behavior, which is what I would expect, would be like this:

```
foreach (AnalyteDTO a in o.Analytes)
{
    string databaseLOINC = a.loinc;
    DateTime databaseDate = o.ObservationDate.Date;

    foreach (Tuple<DateTime, String> lst in allLOINCDatesForPatient)
    {
        if (lst.Item1.Date == databaseDate && lst.Item2.Equals(databaseLOINC))
        {
            isNew = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // no need to continue iterating if we already know the answer...
    if (!isNew)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses `System.Linq` extension methods to query your `observationList`. Though it is not any more efficient than your current implementation, <s>it may be a bit easier to read, and</s> each item in the returned `IEnumerable<Tuple<OneDayAnalytes, bool>>` simply associates each `OneDayAnalytes` with its metric `IsNew`:

```
var tuples = observationsList
    .Select(o => Tuple.Create(o, !o.Analytes
        .Any(a => allLOINCDatesForPatient.Select(t => Tuple.Create(t.Item1.Date, t.Item2))
            .Contains(Tuple.Create<DateTime, String>(o.ObservationDate.Date, a.loinc)))));

foreach (var t in tuples)
{
    var Analytes = t.Item1;
    var IsNew = t.Item2;

    Console.WriteLine("Is New?  -->> " + IsNew.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I thought of using `Contains` rather than another `Any`, but it should be noted that it will work while `allLOINCDatesForPatient` have only `Date`s and not `DateTime`s. (I figured the two `.Date` calls are because of Date vs DateTime comparisons)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just went off the example, I assume that based on the name of the `List`, its granularity is by date. I modified the query slightly, it's starting to look more daunting.